# Is there a laravel function or method for synchronizing updated items

Tags: php, laravel

I have build my application with laravel (one to many relations table) ,and i want to synchronize two update functions .I mean when i update item in this function will update automatically in other function.

I  already create the update functions and works well.What i need to do know is to synchronize the tow updates functions.

```
 $user= User::find($request->userid);
          $fiscal = Fiscal::find($request->fiscal_id);
          $contractuser->fiscal_id= $request->get('fiscal_id');
          $contractuser->contract_id= $request->get('contractid');
          $contractuser->save();
         return redirect()->route('contracts.show',$contractuser->user_id)->with('success','User Contract has been added successfully');
```

This is for contractuser

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $fiscal=Fiscal::find($id);
        $fiscal->name=$request->get('name');
        $fiscal->year=$request->year;
        $fiscal->save();
        return redirect('fiscals');
    }
```

This is for fiscals

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $contract=Contract::find($id);
        $contract->name=$request->get('name');
        $contract->save();
        return redirect('contracts');
    }
```

This is for contract.

The results are good but i want every time i change the fiscal or contract this change will be automatically on user contract .

Comment: Not entirely sure what you need. There's only one update happening in your code snippet. Can you show us the other one?

Comment: I  change the code in my question , you can take a look.

Comment: do you mean you want to create `Contract` & `Fiscal` & link them to the user in the same function ?